# Why does a scala val definition with a dot in it produce an error in a later stage than parsing?

Tags: scala, syntax

In response to a comment from another question, I tried putting this code into Scala:

```
trait Foo

new Foo { self =>
  val self.x = 3
}
```

It doesn't compile, of course, but the error is puzzling me:

```
recursive value x$1 needs type
    val self.x = 3
             ^
```

How did this code get past the parser?

The `-Xprint:parse` is also kind of bizarre:

```
    <synthetic> private[this] val x$1 = 3: @scala.unchecked match {
      case self.x => ()
    }
```

Is that a `match` in the type annotation for `3`? *edit*: Apparently not; that's [the syntax for annotations](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.unchecked).

Comment: Why are you trying to use `self`?

Comment: I don't have a reason for using the above code; it was just suggested to me in a comment.

Comment: Perhaps 'cause it's weird enough not to have been encountered? It most likely is not invalid in the mere syntax of the language (at least as implemented by the currnt compiler's parser) and only in one of the myriad compilation phases is its grammatical incorrectness discovered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variable definitions in Scala are actually *pattern matching*. That is, when you write

```
val x = y
println(x)
```

That's basically the same as writing

```
y match {
  case x =>
    println(x)
```

This can easily be seen in things like this:

```
val List(a, b, c) = someList
val RegexPattern(year, month, date) = "2013-10-23"
```

Another thing that's valid is constant pattern matching:

```
object X {
  val One = 1
}

scala> val X.One = 1

scala> val X.One = 2
scala.MatchError: 2 (of class java.lang.Integer)
```

And anything with a parenthesis will call an extractor:

```
object Y {
  val ymd = """(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)""".r
}

scala> val Y.ymd(year, month, day) = "2013-10-23"
year: String = 2013
month: String = 10
day: String = 23
```

So, you see, there's nothing syntactically illegal with what you wrote, just the specifics.

Comment: I'm using 2.10.3 and the first example with X.One throws an error and why it should work? Y.ymd works cause reg exp has an unnaply, but type of One is an Int: `scala> val X.One = 1
<console>:5: error: value x$3 is not a member of object $iw
  lazy val $result = x$3`

Comment: @AlexIv That's a REPL bug. It exhibits the same behavior with the classic `val 1 = 2`. REPL tries to find a result to display for you and fails sometimes.

Comment: For "assignments", read "variable definitions".  People have asked for assignments, at least for tuples.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. There is still something a little odd, though: based on the `-Xprint:parse` output it appears that on the one hand `x` is treated as a variable in the pattern, and on the other hand it is also treated as a constant.

Comment: @Owen not a constant, but a fresh var, x$1. The x has nothing to do with your x. Change your x to y to demo that it still complains about x$1. Maybe the error means: I need to know if I can unapply on this thing. People have complained that recursive defs are a warn instead of an error; I wonder if your interesting example can be made useful.